# Proving three lines in a triangle meet in a single point

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I've been stuck in this problem for quite some time, it didn't look that difficult at first but I'm struggling, maybe there is something I'm missing. The problem is from 2018 Brazilian math olympiad (https://www.obm.org.br/content/uploads/2018/11/Prova_Nivel_2.pdf), roughly translated by me.

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with circumcenter $O$ and orthocenter
> $H$. A circle with center $X_A$ passes through $A$ and $H$ and
> is tangent to the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$, similarly we
> define points $X_B$ and $X_C$. Let $O_A$, $O_B$ and $O_C$ be symmetric
> to $O$ in relation to sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$, respectively.
>
> Prove that the lines $O_AX_A$, $O_BX_B$ and $O_CX_C$ are concurrent.

I've tried solving it using properties related to circumcenters and orthocenters to see if I could find a relation with which I could use Ceva's theorem, but had no luck.

I found that the triangle $O_AO_BO_C$ is similar to $ABC$ and also they have some relation between their orthocenters and circumcenters, but couldn't do much with that.

Any tips on how to progress would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I guess it's worth adding that the cases for isoceles and equilateral triangles are pretty straightforward, but didn't give me any useful insight. I've been trying to search for a pattern looking at geogebra and moving the vertices, even beyond acute angles, but also had little succes with that.

Comment: Here's the discussion of this problem on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1739654p11305298